# Writing PHP code to creating menu in block show and alert

Tags: 7, routes, blocks, navigation

I have a menu in a block and this is my code in that block that is in **sidebar second**:

```
<?php
  $url=$base_url.'/drupal';
  echo
  '<ul>
  <li><a href="'.$url.'/article/1">One</a></li>
  <li> <a href="'.$url.'/article/2">Two</a></li>
  </ul>';
?>
```

it is working correctly, but return and red alert:

> Notice: Undefined variable: base_url in eval() (line 2 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define it as a global variable first:

```
global $base_url;
```

So that your code is now:

```php
<?php
global $base_url;
$url=$base_url.'/drupal';
echo
'<ul>
<li><a href="'.$url.'/article/1">One</a></li>
<li> <a href="'.$url.'/article/2">Two</a></li>
</ul>';
?>
```

Then you may don't need drupal in your $url variable. and it would become:

```
$url=$base_url;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me more, for example put it in my code.

Comment: You just add that one line in the starting of your code, as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, Drupal Shows a green box with this message: The block configuration has been saved.. :)

Comment: Okay. So, no error message now, right? Happy to help :)